# MongoDb Indexing for MultiTenant

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have two collections, customSchemas, and customdata.  Besides the default _id index, I've added the following indexes

```
db.customData.createIndex( { "orgId": 1, "contentType": 1 });
db.customSchemas.createIndex( { "orgId": 1, "contentType": 1 }, { unique: true });
```

I've decided to enforce orgId on all calls, so in my service layer, every query has an orgId in it, even the ones with ids, e.g.

```
db.customData.find({"_id" : ObjectId("557f30402598f1243c14403c"), orgId: 1});
```

Should I add an index that has both _id and orgId in it?  Do the indexes I have currently help at all when I'm searching by both _id and orgId?

Comment: _id shoud be unique in MongoDB. No reason to add orgId:1 in that query

Comment: The reason is to enforce integrity in multi tenancy.  You never want a user authenticated with orgId 1 to be able to request data for orgId 2.  The only way to be certain is to enforce an orgId on every query that is hard-wired from your authentication mechanism.  Keeping your business is a really good reason.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB 2.6+ provides [index intersection](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/index-intersection/) feature that cover your case by using intersection of **index _id** `{_id:1}` and **index prefix orgId** in `{ "orgId": 1, "contentType": 1 }`

So your query `{"_id" : ObjectId("557f30402598f1243c14403c"), orgId: 1}` should be covered by index already.

However, index intersection is less performant than a compound index on `{"_id" : 1, orgId: 1}`, as it comes with an extra step (intersection of the two sets). Hence, if this is a query that you use most of the time, creating the compound index on it is a good idea.

Comment: A follow up question.  Does the order of the properties in the index matter?  Is  {"_id": 1, "orgId": 1} any different from {"orgId": 1, "_id": 1}?

Comment: When creating compound index for searching (not for sorting), you may consider to put the key with more distinct values first to faciliate the scanning process, in this case  {"_id": 1, "orgId": 1} is more favorable